# Sort array of data to find nearest places

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array of data with multiple objects inside. 1 object is a special place.
Example of data (of course I will write down just first element of array)

```
const data = [
{
  id: 1,
  adress: {
    street: 'Stationsplein',
    number: '1',
    postalCode: '1012 AB'
  },
  city: 'Amsterdam',
  coordinates: {
    latitude: 52.379125,
    longitude: 4.899790
  },
  projectStatus: [
    {
      id: 1,
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      completed: true
    }
  ],
}];
```

And I have user position, for example

```
const userCoordinates = {
  latitude: 52.374413,
  longitude: 4.891736
}
```

How can I sort this array with nearest places ?

Comment: Define nearest: You need a metric for this.

Comment: That's right, @Sascha is correct.  You need to figure out how you want to compute the distance between two coordinates (https://www.thoughtco.com/degree-of-latitude-and-longitude-distance-4070616).  Once you've done that, you can calculate the distance between the user coordinate and all the other coordinates and then sort the array of those distance values.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a good library for my issue.
In my case, it's working perfectly

https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib

Comment: This is a link only answer.  Can you write up the gist of the solution for future readers?